# Using U2net (trained on Coco + DUTS dataset) for foreground segmentation leads to a foreground object being contaminated with colors

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am currently training the [U-2-Net](https://github.com/xuebinqin/U-2-Net/tree/master/test_data/u2netp_results) on a larger dataset of 50k images from scratch.
The results I am getting are already promising. However, they are not perfect. Since my train loss is at around 1.1, further training might increase accuracy.
For the case, my segmented images are still being contaminated with colors from the surroundings, what opportunities do I have to get rid of them in Python?
Would this be another use case for deep learning? Or are there opportunities without machine learning to improve the outcome?
I am aiming for similar results to remove.bg. Their results are absolutely perfect.

Here are some foreground objects after the background has been removed (Have a look at the edges of the objects: the greenish and skin-colored contamination around the T-shirt):
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: they probably trained their model to infer not just the mask but also the "de-multiplied/de-blended" foreground layer. so yes, making this better would require knowing stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Christoph. I am new to the field of machine learning, so it's not clear to me what you mean by "de-multiplied/de-blended". Could you give me a hint? Thx :)

Comment: ok so let's say you have two layers (think photoshop), top one has value A with 50% alpha and bottom one has value B (and 100%). you see how that's a model for edge pixels (dog's fur, etc), yes? ok good, so the blend of that is C = 0.5A + (1-0.5)B. that's a linear combination. if you have C and a guess for the alpha value, you still can't reconstruct both A and B. you have a degree of freedom left. you want A, not A mixed with B (that is your question, reformulated). so you need some way to guess either A or B. that's doable with assumptions about the picture (greenscreen: trivial).

Comment: in this toy example for these specific values, if you could guess B, then A = C/0.5-B. if you could guess A, even better. -- the "mask" inferred by the AI is not an alpha channel. it is just an "object" mask. it will always have trouble in those pixels that aren't clearly either foreground or background. for good separation of objects from a picture, the neural network has to be trained for that task, and be constructed to give you the information you need, which isn't just an alpha channel but also the inferred layer/layers.

Comment: you could cheat... -- get a neural network that infers sharper masks (less fluffy), reducing the halo/feathering -- artificially binarize the mask you do get from your network of choice -- apply morphology operations to shrink the mask so instead of catching some background, you eat into the object pixels, which _also_ isn't great (still noticeable)